# Export java project to jar file in eclipse trouble

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to export my java project into a jar file however I am having difficulty.  The jar file is like a damaged version of the project with the audio and images missing.  My file structure on Eclipses navigator looks like this;
*SkyWars
   *Settings
   *Audio
   *bin
   *images
   *src
     *skyWars (package folder)
     *classpath
     *project

I was told to tick Export generated class files and resources in the jar export pane, click next, then make sure the main class is selected in the final screen before finishing.

Ive trued everything from Exporting the route folder SkyWars to trying src and skyWars.

Is there something wrong with the structure of my project?

Comment: It works inside of eclipse when you run the project? The project works exported minus the images and audio or are you getting some sort of _specific_ error?

Comment: Works perfectly inside eclipse.  Outside it boots up without audio and images, it also looks like text is leaking from all over the program inside the labels and panels.  When i try and export it compile errors pop up for all of the classes inside skyWars.  I don't know if this is relevant but I am also using window builder.

Comment: I just click export as runnable Jar right from Eclipse is that what you are doing?

Comment: I am right clicking the project then selecting export and have tried file>export, is there another way that would do things differently?

Comment: I have tried that but when i do and click the gui for the project in launch configureation and select export destination it comes up JAR creation failed, no resources selected.

Comment: Have you tried package required libraries?

Comment: I have in the last half hour in desperation opened project>properties and in the library tab for my project ontop of jre system library added my classes from skyWars.  Now when extracting it no longer throws up the compiler errors but its still missing both audion and images whilst horribly obscuring everything.

Comment: In these kind of situations I usually just start a new project and copy all my classes to it.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind, can i ask though, do you usually keep your audio and image files in the project folder or the package folder?

Comment: In my main directory I have an assets folder and I dump everything in that. So it is like .settings - assets - bin ... and I dump all my stuff in the assets folder.